# Race condition in Resource ID based locking manager

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to write a locking manager that will be called from multiple threads. This manager handles locking based on various resource IDs. These can vary very much, so keeping a lock in memory for each one would probably cause large memory usage. This is why after a lock is no longer used (the number of threads using it reaches 0), it is removed from memory.

It can exclusively lock threads based on the requested resource ID (if two threads lock the same ID, one will wait for the other to unlock it), or completely exclude all other threads using a ReentrantReadWriteLock.

I am experiencing a race condition where a lock is removed from memory when unlocked by the last thread that holds it, but other threads still try to unlock it? This results in a NPE which I cannot explain.

I have tried using AtomicInteger instead of the current volatile variable, thinking it may have something to do with that but it had similar results.

Here is the problematic class:

```
/**
 * This class provides locks for reading and writing, and bulk operations lock on the entire class.
 * 
 * If a bulk operation is not in progress, class based locking is transparent.
 * @author KiralyCraft
 *
 */
public class ReadWriteHighLevelLocking
{
    private class Semaphore
    {
        private ReentrantLock lock;
        private volatile int acquiredLocks;
        public Semaphore()
        {
            this.acquiredLocks = 0;
            this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        }
        
        public synchronized int incrementAndGet()
        {
            return ++acquiredLocks;
        }
        
        public synchronized int decrementAndGet()
        {
            return --acquiredLocks;
        }
    }
    
    private ReentrantReadWriteLock classBasedLock;
    private volatile HashMap<String, Semaphore> stateChangeLocks;
    
    public ReadWriteHighLevelLocking()
    {
        this.stateChangeLocks = new HashMap<String,Semaphore>();
        this.classBasedLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    }
    
    /**
     * Acquires a lock for the specified resource ID.
     * 
     * May block if another thread is currently holding a bulk lock.
     * @param resourceID
     */
    public void acquireLock(String resourceID)
    {
        classBasedLock.readLock().lock(); //Using it reversed. There can be any number of operations (using the read lock), but only one bulk operation (sacrifice)
        Semaphore stateChangeLock;
        synchronized(stateChangeLocks)
        {
            if ((stateChangeLock = stateChangeLocks.get(resourceID))==null)
            {
                stateChangeLocks.put(resourceID, (stateChangeLock = new Semaphore()));
            }
        }
        stateChangeLock.lock.lock();
        stateChangeLock.incrementAndGet();
    }
    public void releaseLock(String resourceID)
    {
        Semaphore stateChangeLock;
        synchronized(stateChangeLocks)
        {
            stateChangeLock = stateChangeLocks.get(resourceID);
            if (stateChangeLock.decrementAndGet() == 0)  //<----------------- HERE IS THE NPE
            {
                stateChangeLocks.remove(resourceID);
            }
        }
        stateChangeLock.lock.unlock();
        classBasedLock.readLock().unlock();
    }
    
    /**
     * When a bulk lock is acquired, all other operations are delayed until this one is released.
     */
    public void acquireBulkLock()
    {
        classBasedLock.writeLock().lock();  //Using it reversed. There can be any number of writers (using the read lock), but only one reader (sacrifice)
    }
    
    public void releaseBulkLock()
    {
        classBasedLock.writeLock().unlock(); 
    }
}
```

Sample caller class:

```
public abstract class AbstractDatabaseLockingController
{
    ...
    private ReadWriteHighLevelLocking highLevelLock;
    
    public AbstractDatabaseLockingController(DatabaseInterface db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.highLevelLock = new ReadWriteHighLevelLocking();
    }   
    ...
    public <T extends DatabaseIdentifiable> boolean executeSynchronizedUpdate(T theEntity,AbstractSynchronousOperation<T> aso)
    {
        boolean toReturn;
        String lockID = theEntity.getId()+theEntity.getClass().getSimpleName();
        highLevelLock.acquireLock(lockID);
        toReturn = aso.execute(theEntity,db);
        highLevelLock.releaseLock(lockID);
        return toReturn;        
    }
    ...
    public <T extends DatabaseIdentifiable> List<T> executeSynchronizedGetAllWhereFetch(Class<T> objectType, DatabaseQuerySupplier<T> dqs)
    {
        List<T> toReturn;
        highLevelLock.acquireBulkLock();
        toReturn = db.getAllWhere(objectType, dqs);
        highLevelLock.releaseBulkLock();
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

NOTE: All places where such a locking manager is used follow the acquire/release pattern from the sample class. It's basically the only place where it is used. Other threads may call the above methods indirectly through the sample class's children

Comment: On a high level look, stateChangeLock = stateChangeLocks.get(resourceID); was never initialized, can you provide a sample Thread class the way it is acquiring the locks??

Comment: Yes, I've added a sample of the calling class. The locks are always acquired first, and released after, I've double checked that

Comment: Well, can you try making stateChangeLocks as final, as the synchronized statements where the lock expression is a reference to a non-final field, such statements are unlikely to have useful semantics, as different threads may be locking on different objects even when operating on the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the issue by updating the following code:

```
    synchronized(stateChangeLocks)
    {
        if ((stateChangeLock = stateChangeLocks.get(resourceID))==null)
        {
            stateChangeLocks.put(resourceID, (stateChangeLock = new Semaphore()));
        }
    }
    stateChangeLock.lock.lock();
    stateChangeLock.incrementAndGet();
```

to

```
    synchronized(stateChangeLocks)
    {
        if ((stateChangeLock = stateChangeLocks.get(resourceID))==null)
        {
            stateChangeLocks.put(resourceID, (stateChangeLock = new Semaphore()));
        }
        stateChangeLock.incrementAndGet();
    }
    stateChangeLock.lock.lock();
```